# When executing ng serve command using terminal in angular 4 i got an error

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, sass

I have an application in which i am using angular 4 when i run ng server the following errors are getting hit .

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./node_modules/angular-star-rating/assets/scss/star-rating.scss
Module build failed: 
@import "~css-star-rating/dist/scss/star-rating.scss";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: ~css-star-rating/dist/scss/star-rating.scss.
      in E:\Health-Pro-Web\node_modules\angular-star-rating\assets\scss\star-rating.scss (line 1, column 1)
Error: 
@import "~css-star-rating/dist/scss/star-rating.scss";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: ~css-star-rating/dist/scss/star-rating.scss.
      in E:\Health-Pro-Web\node_modules\angular-star-rating\assets\scss\star-rating.scss (line 1, column 1)
    at options.error (E:\Health-Pro-Web\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
 @ ./node_modules/angular-star-rating/assets/scss/star-rating.scss 4:14-171
 @ multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
./src/styles.css ./node_modules/angular-star-rating/assets/scss/star-rating.scss ./node_modules/ngx-intl-tel-input/resource/intl-tel-input.css
ERROR in E:/Health-Pro-Web/node_modules/ng2-date-countdown/lib/countdown.ts (4,13): Cannot find name 'module'.ERROR in E:/Health-Pro-Web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/google-maps-types.d.ts (579,19): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.
ERROR in E:/Health-Pro-Web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/google-maps-types.d.ts (580,24): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.
ERROR in E:/Health-Pro-Web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/google-maps-types.d.ts (581,26): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.
ERROR in E:/Health-Pro-Web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/google-maps-types.d.ts (582,15): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.
ERROR in E:/Health-Pro-Web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/google-maps-types.d.ts (602,13): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.
ERROR in E:/Health-Pro-Web/src/app/custom-pipe/pipe.module.ts (13,22): Cannot find name 'ModuleWithProviders'.ERROR in E:/Health-Pro-Web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/google-maps-types.d.ts (604,10): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.
ERROR in E:/Health-Pro-Web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/google-maps-types.d.ts (605,24): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.
ERROR in E:/Health-Pro-Web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/google-maps-types.d.ts (606,22): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.
ERROR in E:/Health-Pro-Web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/google-maps-types.d.ts (607,21): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.
ERROR in E:/Health-Pro-Web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/google-maps-types.d.ts (608,20): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module E:/Health-Pro-Web/node_modules/@agm/core/agm-core.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in E:/Health-Pro-Web/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in E:/Health-Pro-Web/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in E:/Health-Pro-Web/src/app/app.module.ts
    at syntaxError (E:\Health-Pro-Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
    at simplifyInContext (E:\Health-Pro-Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (E:\Health-Pro-Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (E:\Health-Pro-Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
    at _getNgModuleMetadata (E:\Health-Pro-Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
    at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (E:\Health-Pro-Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (E:\Health-Pro-Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (E:\Health-Pro-Web\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (E:\Health-Pro-Web\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:207:44)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (E:\Health-Pro-Web\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:443:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
ERROR in E:/Health-Pro-Web/node_modules/@agm/core/services/google-maps-types.d.ts (603,23): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.
```

Comment: delete the project's `node_modules` directory if it exists, then run `npm install`.

Comment: Same issue still exists after uninstalling npm and then reinstalling